# Java executable jar get file

Tags: java, jar, gate

I need an executable jar for my program. A part of the program contains the Gate entity extraction tool.
Here is the part of the code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("annie.gapp").getFile());  
// CorpusController application = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(
        //new File("annie.gapp"));

CorpusController application = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(
        file);
```

In eclipse everything is working, but if I export it as executable jar file it does not find the annie.gapp file, and I don’t know how to make it work (I have already looked here on Stackoverflow)

Comment: How do you export as executable jar?

Comment: I exported it from eclipse. export - java - runnable jar file. The annie.gapp file and everything from gate gets exported but loading the file does not work

Comment: ok, I could solve it. Instead of loadObjectFromFile it is possible to load annie.gapp from an URL (loadObjectFromUrl)

Comment: A .jar file is a single archive file.  Entries in a .jar are not files.  You cannot refer to them as files.  And the URL.getFile() does not convert a URL to a file name, it just returns the path portion of a URL.